# Regex for preventing 'test@xx.xxx' in email fields

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex to validate email fields. it accepts any string before '@' character. I want to prevent user entering junk email ids like 'test@xxx.com' or 'spam@xxx.xx.xx' etc.

I am using data abide for validations and below is the regex:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?!([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.))(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/g
```

Comment: How would you define all junk email ids?

Comment: Why? Because while you might successfully blacklist `'spam'` and `'test'`, how are you guarding against `'dsrrgtergtergterger'` (or whatever else)?

Comment: Scenario: I have to enter an email address where I don't want to. I use `spam@hotmail.com`. Get rejected. Option 1: Leave and never come back. Option 2: Enter `george.w.bush@hotmail.com`. Which one would you prefer?

Comment: @David, one of my closest friends is called Dsrrgtergtergterger Johannes ChrisDeBurgh Wallwalla Smith, you insensitive clod :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't bother.

The **ONLY** way of confirming email addresses is sending a confirmation email and wait for the answer.

Comment: This! A hundred times over. There are literally millions of perfectly valid email addresses that are "invalid" because there's no backing account. To ensure an email is valid, send a link email to it and only allow user to proceed once they've actined that link.

Comment: If a user doesn't want to enter a valid address, then you're probably offering a service where the user doesn't see any need for you to have their email address. In that case, asking them for confirmation is unlikely to help. Don't collect email addresses if you don't need to.